# Same width flex items except for the last one

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have a three column layout where every div fits within 1/3 of the container except for the last item, which spans the remaining columns.

I have a working example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZYLjY I'm looking to get every gray box to have the same width and have the blue boxes expand to fill the rest of the remaining space.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.child {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
}

.parent {
  border: 5px solid #EEEEEE;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.child {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}

.child:last-child {
  background-color: #1FBBE6;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.child {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);
}

.child:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgwrOr)

Every child has the same width: 33.33% less the horizontal margins.

The last child will have the same width *and* consume remaining space in the row, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 things:

```
.child:last-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because the gray boxes do not end up being equal in width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-width` in combination with a true 33.333% flexbox.  You would then just set `max-width: none` for the `last-child`.  I've added `box-sizing:border-box` and I've swapped your `margin: $gutter` with a white border of the same width to maintain a true 33% width.  Ideally, you should instead have a child inside each `.child` that provides your background color and margin, but in any case, here's my attempt: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GERZKj